# Rails bundler doesn't install gems inside a group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have several gems including ruby-debug in a bundler group called :development. When I run the bundle command, these gems are ignored and it only installs the gems that are not in any group. How can I make sure bundler doesn't ignore the gems in the :development group?

Edit: This is what my Gemfile looks like.

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.1'

# Auth gems
gem "devise", "1.1.3"
gem "omniauth"

# Bundle Mongoid gems
gem "mongoid", "2.0.0.beta.19"
gem "bson_ext"

# Asset gems
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "jammit"

# Controller gems
gem 'inherited_resources', '1.1.2'

# View gems
gem 'haml'
gem 'formtastic', '~> 1.1.0'

# Nokogiri
gem "mechanize"
gem "json"


group :development do
  gem "ruby-debug"
  gem 'compass'
  gem 'compass-colors'
  gem 'pickler'
  gem 'haml-rails'
  gem 'rails3-generators'
  gem "hpricot"
  gem "ruby_parser"
  gem 'fog'
end
```

Comment: Yep, checked. Rails.env says development.

Comment: There is another thing. I had used this command earlier because Heroku was not excluding those gems: heroku config:add BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development test" That didn't make a difference for Heroku, though. http://www.mail-archive.com/heroku@googlegroups.com/msg06114.html

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Within a term session, it remembers the `without` option. If you first ran

```
bundle install --without development
```

it remembers that you did this and will automatically repeat this for the next

```
bundle install #remembers and includes --without development
```

running something else, like `bundle install --without nothing` should clear the cache. Am  I right?

**update 20150214:** This is fixed in bundler 2.0, according to issue referenced in comment by @Stan Bondi (https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2862). Thanks Stan.

Comment: This saved put an end to my frustrations!!! Doing `rm .bundle/config` is the best way to clear the cache.

Comment: Just got bitten by this. Command line flags should be stateless.

Comment: Thanks! Made an issue (woah 3 years later!) https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2862

Comment: Could not locate Gemfile, why ?

Answer (score 35):

If you are using rails, there will be a file `config` written into a hidden dir called `.bundle` in your rails root directory:

```
.bundle/config
```

This file, in my case, held exactly the `without` settings.

So I just deleted the `.bundle` directory:

```
rm .bundle -r
```

After that:

`bundle install` worked again as expected.

```
Using: bundler (1.5.2)
```

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue and `--with` flag worked for me. You need to pass group name, which you want to include. Like that:

```
bundle install --with development
```

Comment: Please add more description to your post. How exactly it helps to resove issue mentioned in the question

Comment: This is deprecated now. Use `bundle config set --local` instead

Answer (score 2):

```
    gem 'aws-s3'
    gem 'paperclip'
      group :test do
        gem 'rspec'
        gem 'waitr'
        gem 'faker'
      end

gem 'rest-client', :group => :development
gem 'cucuber-rails', :groups => [:development,:test]  (cucuber-rails gems comes under both group)

bundle install --without development #(ignore development group gems)
bundle install #(still bundle remembers --without development so result is still ignore development groups it will not install all gems)

bundle install --without nothing #(just clearing cache, now all the gems to be loaded into the ruby loadpath)
```

[More](http://madhan-tech-updates.blogspot.in/2013/02/how-to-install-gems-group-specific-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

In fact Rails loads the `:development` group automatically when in development environment. Check whether `Rails.env` in you App really returns `"development"`.

More Information about groups in Bundler:
http://gembundler.com/groups.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - thin in staging ignored - and the solution was to put it out if staging into the 'global' space:

```
gem 'thin'

group :production do
  gem 'puma'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue with `bundler 2.1.4` When I checked my `.bundle/config` it has

```
---
BUNDLE_PATH: "vendor/bundle"
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: "development:test:build"
```

Remove groups from there and add `BUNDLE_WITH` to your groups.

```
BUNDLE_WITH: "development"
```

I've removed the `~/.bundle/config`. but there was a file in my project directory. `.bundle/config`. Local directory files have precedence over the main config files.

If you can't figure out the reason, then you can just create a file in your project directory `.bundle/config`. and add this content there

```
BUNDLE_WITH: "development:test:anyGroupYouWant"
```