# Middleman - Unknown Extension: livereload

Tags: ruby, middleman

Trying to just get started building a site with Middleman, and I'm following the tutorial to a t, but when I start the server I always get "Unknown Extension: livereload"

I already have

```
group :development do
  gem 'middleman-livereload'
end
```

and

```
configure : development do
  activate :livereload
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried "bundle update" command in your project directory?

Comment: Tried it just now, doesn't seem to be the cause. Any other ideas? :(

Comment: Have you added "gem 'middleman-livereload'" line to the "Gemfile" file? If the first snippet is from the Gemfile, may be try to remove ":development" condition for testing?

Comment: ROFL I guess that is what it was. I wonder why the group thing doesn't work. I'm still really new to this stuff, I've never had a problem doing that in rails, but obviously this is different. Perhaps the article I'm following on setting it up is outdated and that stuff doesn't work any more?

Comment: May be :) I never used such a conditions. May by you should specify bundler options as described at the http://bundler.io/groups.html and http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/09/the-how-and-why-of-bundler-groups/ ?

Comment: You can check also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118055/rails-bundler-doesnt-install-gems-inside-a-group

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem. For some reason LiveReload isn't recognized when you include it in a `group` in your Gemfile. My fix:

```
gem 'middleman-livereload' # NOTE: breaks if placed inside a group!
group :middleman do
  gem 'middleman'
end
```

I'm using `middleman` **3.3.12** and `middleman-livereload` **3.4.2**

Answer (score 0):

I started with the blog flag out of the box.

`middleman init MY_BLOG_PROJECT --template=blog`

So, for me, the gem was never part of the original `GEMFILE`. My solution was to add the gem.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'middleman-livereload'
```

*Ruby Static Sites FTW!*