# LoadError: cannot load such file -- rspec/core/rake_task

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems, rake

When I rake, I got this error.

```
AllenLins-MacBook-Pro:geoblacklight allenlin$ rake -t
Resolving dependencies...
You must `gem install bundler` and `bundle install` to run rake tasks
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rspec/core/rake_task
/Users/allenlin/Documents/USpatial/geoblacklight/Rakefile:12:in `require'
/Users/allenlin/Documents/USpatial/geoblacklight/Rakefile:12:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

**However, I've run the 'gem install bundler' and 'bundle install' the rspec/core/rake_task actually exists, shown by**

```
AllenLins-MacBook-Pro:geoblacklight allenlin$ gem which rspec/core/rake_task
/Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb
```

I am lost here. Thanks so much for any help on this! I attached the Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Specify your gem's dependencies in geoblacklight.gemspec
gemspec

# If we don't specify 2.11.0 we'll end up with sprockets 2.12.0 in the main
# Gemfile.lock but since sass-rails gets generated (rails new) into the test app
# it'll want sprockets 2.11.0 and we'll have a conflict
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'

# If we don't specify 3.2.15 we'll end up with sass 3.3.2 in the main
# Gemfile.lock but since sass-rails gets generated (rails new) into the test app
# it'll want sass 3.2.0 and we'll have a conflict
gem 'sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', ">= 3.2"

group :test do
  # Peg simplecov to < 0.8 until this is resolved:
  # https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/issues/281
  gem 'simplecov', '~> 0.7.1', require: false
  gem 'coveralls', require: false
end
```

**Update**

Add my gem env if that's helpful

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.2 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-darwin14]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/allenlin/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
     - /Users/allenlin/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec
     - /Users/allenlin/.rbenv/shims
     - /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin
     - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
     - /Users/allenlin/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin
     - /Users/allenlin/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/bin
     - /Users/allenlin/gradle-1.12/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /Users/allenlin/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /opt/X11/bin
     - /usr/local/git/bin
     - /usr/texbin
```

Comment: (1)this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources. (2)Your Gemfile lists the gem geoblacklight (>= 0) more than once.(3)You must `gem install bundler` and `bundle install`

Comment: @pangpang Thanks for your reply! I've updated the post! Essentially, I don't understand why the error and warning messages say that I have multiple 'source' and geoblacklight. Is there any other files I should look into?

Comment: What happened when you followed this instruction: "(See full trace by running task with --trace)" ? :)

Comment: Also - the whole file-expand-path bit at the bottom. isn't that just loading the same Gemfile a second time? That might be why you're getting "two sources" and two of everything else too

Comment: @TarynEast Thanks for reminding me that! :) Please see the full trace!

Comment: @TarynEast And just tried deleting the last block of code - you are right that the last block loads Gemfile the second time which creates the warning message. But the other error messages are exactly the same when I ran without the last block of code.

Comment: Please run `rake -T`

Comment: @pangpang Yes, just did what you said. Please see the edited post! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you check the bundler version?  `bundler -v`

Comment: @pangpang Yes, it's Bundler version 1.9.6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77266/discussion-between-pangpang-and-allen-lin).

Comment: Issue is still not solved. Sad :( Please let me know if there is any other additional information I could provide!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems that running `bundle exec rake -t` will work. Per bundler.io http://bundler.io/man/bundle-exec.1.html 
I suggest adding bundle exec to ensure that we are using the Gem specified in the current context. Also see this SO post. [What does bundle exec rake mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588674/what-does-bundle-exec-rake-mean)

Comment: -t just adds a trace

Answer (score 15):

After having earlier run : `sudo gem install bundler`

I created a Gemfile with:

```
gem 'rake'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'kramdown'
```

and did `bundle install`. Now I dont get the error.

Answer (score 2):

### In Production Environment

What happens is, `capistrano` is configured to only install gem bundle in `production` group(as in Gemfile). So it runs bundle command like `bundle install --without development test`.

#### Want to verify?

Run `bundle install` command in project dir in Production environment, you will see following

```
Using devise 4.2.0
Using activeadmin 1.0.0.pre4
Using responsive_active_admin 0.0.5
Bundle complete! 60 Gemfile dependencies, 133 gems now installed.
Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
Bundled gems are installed into /path/to/your/app/production/shared/bundle.
```

Please note (**Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.**).

**You might recall that you have specified `rspec-rails` gem to be installed in `development` mode only.**

---

#### Solution

try to specify the `RAILS_ENV` like

```
# For Rails 5.0 +
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails -T

# or 

RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake -T

# but this may not work
bundle exec rake -T RAILS_ENV=production
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you actually have rspec in your Gemfile, if you're getting this error it either means you're not running rake with the proper gems your application needs (use `bundle exec rake` from your application's root directory to solve), or that your rspec core gem has not been installed.

If after running `bundle install`, you still get the same error when running `bundle exec rake`, check that you've actually installed your "test mode" gems. This happened to me.

In my case, I had not installed my test gems because Bundler exhibits unconventional behavior by remembering the previous arguments passed to the `--without` option [as noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4143287/828858), so it could be that you think you're installing all your gems when you run `bundle install` but you might actually be running with (for example...) `--without development test` as well and not know it.

Check for something like "Gems in the groups development and test were not installed." at the end of your `bundle install` output.

To reset your bundle options, simply remove your `./.bundle` dir (so... `rm -r ./.bundle`). Now `bundle install` will be back to normal and rake should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because in my gem file I did not specified the version of rspec and it got the old version.
I updated my gem file to it:

`gem 'rspec', '3.8.0'`

and it worked!

Comment: Sure enough `gem install rspec` fixed it.