# travis failing to run rake with LoadError: cannot load such file -- rspec/core/rake_task

Tags: ruby, rspec, travis-ci

Let me preface this with this all runs locally and succeeds.

- [Source code repo](https://github.com/alienfast/gulp-pipeline-rails)
- [Travis log for job #4.1](https://travis-ci.org/alienfast/gulp-pipeline-rails/jobs/118264057)

Error:

```
$ rake
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rspec/core/rake_task
/home/travis/build/alienfast/gulp-pipeline-rails/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

.travis.yml

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.2.2
  - ruby-head

matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - rvm: ruby-head

cache: bundler

before_script:
  # install Gulp 4 CLI tools globally from 4.0 GitHub branch
  - npm install gulpjs/gulp-cli#4.0 -g

script: rake
```

Gemfile

```
gemspec


# travis-ci quirk?
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rake'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
end
```

Fix attempts:

- Locally, I have emptied my rvm gemset, deleted locks, and replicated the travis build - still works
- I tried moving the necessary test gems from the `gemspec` to the `Gemfile`

---

So I'm pretty confused, I have other projects that don't have this problem and I don't see anything obvious.  Is there any reason to get `LoadError: cannot load such file -- rspec/core/rake_task`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `bundle exec rake -t` As noted here [LoadError: cannot load such file -- rspec/core/rake_task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114733/loaderror-cannot-load-such-file-rspec-core-rake-task)